# Add table IDs only to parent tables using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page:

```
<html>
<head>
<body text="#000000" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<style type="text/css">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="page-break-after:always;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
</body>
</html>
```

I need to add unique IDs to each of these parent tables. The problem is, each of these tables has many nested tables. I need to only add IDs to each of these shown. How do I do so? I tried:

```
jQuery("table").each(function(count){
    var count = count + 1;
    jQuery(this).attr("id","table"+count+"");
});
```

But this adds unique IDs to all tables, even the nested ones. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using direct child something like `body > table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you can simply target the parent `table` elements (i.e. those which are direct descendents of `body`) as follows:

```
$('body > table').each(function(i) {
    $(this).prop('id', 'table'+(i + 1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("body > table").each(function(count){
var count = count + 1;
jQuery(this).attr("id","table"+count+"");
});
```

this will select direct child (table) of body and it should work for you i believe